# Obtaining a random var. with mean 0 and standard dev. 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbf P)$ be a probability space. Suppose a random variable $X$ has expectation $\mu=\mathbf E(X)$ and variance $\sigma^2=\mathrm{Var}(X)$. Does the random variable $Y$ given by $Y=\frac{X-\mu}\sigma$ satisfy $\mathbf E(Y)=0$ and Var$(Y)=1$?

Comment: Yes.  This is the usual way of "standardizing" a random variable.

Comment: Unless $\sigma = 0$...

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: $\mathrm E[Y]=\mathrm E[(X-\mu)/\sigma]=\mathrm E[X]/\sigma-\mathrm E[\mu/\sigma]$

$\mathrm {var}(X)=\mathrm E[X^2]-\mathrm E[X]^2$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does, since
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{\mathbb{V}ar}[Y] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\right]-\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right]^2 =\frac{\operatorname{\mathbb{V}ar}[X]}{\sigma^2} =1, \\
\mathbb{E}[Y]&=\mathbb{E}\left[\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right]=\frac{1}{\sigma}\left(\mathbb{E}[X]-\mu\right)=0.
\end{align*}